# Get information from a numpy array

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a numpy array which is 5 by 182 that looks similar to something like this:

```
matched_data = '/home/myname/data.csv'
matched_data = Table.read(matched_data, format="ascii")

ID_1 = np.array(matched_data['name'])
ID_1.astype(str)

ID_2 = np.array(matched_data['col1_1'])
ID_2.astype(str)

mag = np.array(matched_data['Magnitude'])
mag.astype(float)

semi_major_axis = np.array(matched_data['SMA'])
semi_major_axis.astype(float)

semi_minor_axis = np.array(matched_data['sma'])
semi_minor_axis.astype(float)

position_angle = np.array(matched_data['pos_ang'])
position_angle.astype(float)


match = (ID_1, ID_2, mag, (semi_major_axis/semi_minor_axis), position_angle)
match = np.array(match)
```

How would I be able to get data out of this line by line? For example when I type :

```
print(match[0])
```

it prints out the list of IDs from ID_1 where as I would like the ID_1, ID_2, magnitude, (semi_major_axis/semi_minor_axis) and position_angle of the first object. How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `match = np.array(match)` you can use `match = np.stack(match, axis=1)`. This way the various quantities (`ID_1, ID_2, mag, ...`) will be columns of the resulting array and you can access them via `match[index]`. If you did `np.stack(match, axis=0)` then this is similar to what you did originally and the data will be rows in the resulting array. Here it's still possible to access it by providing a column index: `match[:, 0]`.